# How do I get the MIN value from two columns along with corresponding id?

Tags: mysql, min

My query does return the lowest price from the two columns (price_base, price_special) but it is not returning the correct store_id that corresponds to the lowest price found.

My Query:

```
SELECT grocery_item.id, grocery_item.category,
grocery_category.name AS cat, grocery_item.name AS itemName,
MIN( if( grocery_price.price_special>0,
grocery_price.price_base)) AS price,
grocery_price.store_id,
grocery_store.name AS storeName
FROM grocery_item
LEFT JOIN grocery_category ON
grocery_category.id=grocery_item.category
LEFT JOIN grocery_price
ON grocery_price.item_id = grocery_item.id
LEFT JOIN grocery_store 
ON grocery_store.id=grocery_price.store_id   
WHERE grocery_price.selection='no'
AND buy='yes'
GROUP BY grocery_price.item_id
ORDER BY store_id, grocery_item.category, grocery_item.name
```

Returns this:

```
ID  category    cat     itemName       price    store_id    storeName
92  3   Bread/Bakery    Arnold Bread    2.14    1           Food Lion
```

But the grocery_price table holds this info:

```
item_id price_base  price_special   store_id
92      4.29        2.14            9
92      3.99        0.00            1
```

so the store_id I need to be returned is 9 (the storeName returned would NOT then be Food Lion)

EDIT: WORKING QUERY based on Uueerdo's comments (thank you!)

```
SELECT minP.item_id, gi.category, gc.name AS cat,
gi.name as itemName,  gp.store_id, 
gs.name AS storeName, minP.price
FROM
(SELECT p.item_id, MIN(IF(p.price_special >0,
p.price_special,p.price_base)) AS price
FROM grocery_item AS i
INNER JOIN grocery_price AS p ON (i.id = p.item_id)
WHERE i.buy = 'yes'
GROUP BY p.item_id) AS minP
INNER JOIN grocery_item AS gi ON minP.item_id = gi.id
INNER JOIN grocery_category AS gc on gi.category = gc.id 
LEFT JOIN grocery_price AS gp
ON minP.price = IF(gp.price_special > 0,
gp.price_special,gp.price_base)
AND gp.item_id = gi.id
INNER JOIN grocery_store AS gs ON gp.store_id = gs.id
GROUP BY gi.id
ORDER BY gs.id, gi.category,gi.name
```

Comment: Use JOIN ... ON instead of FROM table1,table2,...

Comment: Use proper `JOIN` syntax!!!  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  This query doesn't even run.  Columns `t1.name,t1.category, grocery_category.name AS cat, t1.name AS itemName, t1.buy,grocery_price.store_id, grocery_store.name AS storeName` are not in `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values returned for non-grouped, non-aggregated fields are an (effectively) random selection from the values encountered with the grouped fields' values. Most RDBMS do not even consider such a query valid, and even newer versions of MySQL default to disallowing such queries.

In cases like yours, where you need the non-grouped value(s) associated with the aggregate result (min in this case); the aggregating query must be converted into a subquery, that can be joined back to the aggregated tables to find the source row(s) that correspond to the aggregated value.

Edit: Basically, you need to look at the problem slightly differently. You're currently finding the lowest price for an item and **a store** that item is listed for; you need to find the lowest price for an item, and use that to find the **store(s)** that have the item at that price.

---

This gets you the lowest price for item's marked "buy":

```
SELECT p.item_id, MIN(IF(p.price_special > 0,p.price_special,p.price_base)) AS price
FROM grocery_item AS i
INNER JOIN grocery_price AS p ON (i.id = p.item_id)
WHERE i.buy = 'yes'
GROUP BY p.item_id
```

You can then take that to get the rest of the results:

```
SELECT minP.item_id
   , gi.name
   , gi.category, gc.category_name AS cat, gi.Name as itemName, gi.buy
   , gp.store_id, gp.name AS storeName
   , minP.price
FROM ([the query above]) AS minP
INNER JOIN grocery_item AS gi ON minP.item_id = gi.id
INNER JOIN grocery_category AS gc on gi.category = gc.grocery_category_id 
    /* Guessing on this join since grocery_category_id 
       was not qualified with it's table name */
INNER JOIN grocery_price AS gp 
   ON minP.price = IF(gp.price_special > 0,gp.price_special,gp.price_base)
   /* Alternatively: ON minP.price IN (gp.price_special, gp.price_base) 
      ... though this could cause false positives if the minP.price is 0 
          from one store's base price being "free"
   */
INNER JOIN grocery_store AS gs ON gp.store_id = gs.id
;
```

Comment: "you need to find the lowest price for an item, and use that to find the store(s) that have the item at that price" - this makes sense although I've been unable to figure it out.

Comment: @bp163 Added the final query (in two parts for easier understanding); also note how the joining (and the order I did the joins in) make the connections clearer than a list of tables with a list of conditions that happen to "join" them.